# Checking data on primary key violation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

If I try to insert data into a table which already contains that primary key, it will clearly fail.

Is there a simple way to check whether the data I've failed to insert *matches* what is already in the table? (ie, if the non-primary key fields are the same as are already there for that primary key)

Ideally rather than get a single error, I would like to get 2 different errors when I attempt to insert a primary key that is already used:

```
- Error1: primary key constraint broken - data being inserted is already in table
- Error2: primary key constraint broken - attempt to enter different data for existing primary key
```

Comment: Yes, there is. `SELECT` query.

Comment: With other words, you want to figure out the tables' constraints?

Comment: I could do a SELECT, but then I need to parse the command I am trying to execute, and compare, which could get complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check you can do something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM tab1
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM tab2
);
```

`UNION` removes duplicates so if rows in both tables are identical then above query will return identical result as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1;
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab2;
```

Your question is not very detailed (e.g. how you insert this data?) so my answer in also quite generic, but I belive it will be useful for you.

Comment: thanks, that is useful. My insert is done via a mysqlCommand from c#

Answer (score 2):

Try it with this:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (field1, field2, field3...)
SELECT yourValue1, yourValue2, yourValue3...
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM yourTable 
                  WHERE field1 = yourValue1
                  AND field2 = yourValue2
                  AND field3 = yourValue3...);
```

This query checks your fields and only inserts when the record is not already there.

Comment: right, but it doesn't tell me whether the non-primary key fields match what is already there.

Comment: you add your non-primary fields as parameters. So you compare exactly those fields and only insert it if they are not there.